# Dynamic combo box list issue

Tags: swt

Using switch case i wanted to add different list to combobox,when i compile i dont see any error. The following is my code, can any one please suggest what could be the reason for not updating combobox list ??

```
public void comboboxlist(Composite parent,String fruit) {
    Combo combobox = new Combo(parent,SWT.NONE | SWT.DROP_DOWN | SWT.READ_ONLY);
    switch(fruit) {
        case "apple":
            combobox.setItems(new String[]{"Red","green"});
            combobox.addModifyListener( new ModifyListener() {
                public void modifyText(final ModifyEvent e) {   
                }
            });
            break;
        case "mango":
            combobox.setItems(new String[]{"Yellow","green"});
            combobox.addModifyListener( new ModifyListener() {
                public void modifyText(final ModifyEvent e) {   
                }
            });
            break;
            default : break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like swt code, not swing. Retagging...

Comment: so you mean i can't do in this way?

Comment: No, I mean that you tagged your question with "swing", and you're not using Swing but SWT.

Answer (score 1):

The most plausible explanation for me would be that your fruit is neither "apple" nor "mango". Have you checked that?